# How to create symbols

Tags: support, question-quality, specific-question

I'm making a code in which

> I convert Braille to symbols by drawing lines between adjacent dots, two lines with circles attached at the ends for dots with spaces in between them, and a single circle to symbolize single dots.

What software should I use to do this? Also, has this been done multiple times?

Comment: Meta is only for questions about the site itself. You may be able to ask on the main site, though I think it would be too broad. (For one, any paint program would work...)